# Changing boolean value in API Mongo MERN React Node

Tags: node.js, reactjs, database, mongodb, api

I am getting error 404 that the API cannot be found.  The Boolean in API is "auto_delete".  I want to change it to true when this is referenced.

I wrote a button to reference a function that would reference this API but OnClick it will not be able to find this API apparently.

I posted first the front end file with constructor/binding, button, and function.  I then put API at bottom.

Any input would help.

```
//FRONT END
This is the front end with button and function button references to

//CONSTRUCTOR AND BINDING FUNCTION
export default class VideoContent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    let video = this.props.video;
    let user = this.props.user;
    this.state = {
      fetchDuration: false,
      viewed: false,
      subscribed:
        user &&
        user.hasOwnProperty("follows") &&
        user.follows.includes(video.author)
    };
    
    
    this.view = this.view.bind(this);
    this.report = this.report.bind(this);
    this.reportJ= this.reportJ.bind(this);
    
  }




<Button
                      disabled={user ? !user.userId : true}
                      onClick={this.reportJ}
                      style={{ float: "right", backgroundColor: "purple" }}
                    >
                      ReportJ
                    </Button>

//FUNCTION
reportJ() {
    const { video, user } = this.props;
    confirmAlert({
      title: "Confirm Objectionable Content",
      message: "You Sure Fool?",
      buttons: [
        {
          label: "Yes",
          onClick: () => {
            axios
              .post(
                inDev
                  ? devAPI.concat("reportJ")
                  : baseAPI.concat("reportJ"),
                {
                  id: video._id,
                  update: {
                    auto_delete: true
                  }
                }
              )
              .then(res => {
                this.setState({ changed: true });
              })
              .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
              });
          }
        },
        {
          label: "No",
          onClick: () => alert("Nevermind")
        }
      ]
    });
  }

//SERVER JS File with API below

router.post("/reportJ", (req, res) => {
    const { id, update } = req.body;
    models.Videos.findById(id, function (err, video) {
        video.auto_delete = true;
        video.save((err, data) => {
            if (err)
                return res.json({
                    success: false,
                    error: err
                });

            return res.json({
                success: true,
                data: data
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: If you're getting a 404 the problem probably lies with your client code and not the code you've posted. Either the URL you are making the POST request to in your front end doesn't match the route in the API, or the API isn't running.

Comment: I will update post

Comment: I would suggest maybe testing your API endpoints with something like Postman to make sure it's working as expected.